# Chained DIVs in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to do this in HAML

```
<div class="a"><div class="b"><div class="c"><div class="d">
Hello World
</div></div></div></div>
```

The way the documentation do is

```
.a
  .b
    .c
      .d
        Hello World
```

I want the HAML code to be in one line. Is this possible? Should be something like:

```
.a>.b>.c>.d
  Hello World
```

Comment: Just wondering why you don't make it `<div class="a b c d">Hello</div>`. But thats not your question :)

Comment: The documented example is so much easier to read. Even if your example were possible in Haml, I wouldn't recommend using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a drastic difference in syntax if this would be possible in haml; it is not. At the heart of haml stands the idea that you can create container tags with indentation. Replacing this would be a lot of work, and in my opinion quite unnecessary.